# Bound Button Not Enabling After Background Worker Process Completes

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a background worker process that starts provisioning a new client for our system.  Here is what the DoWork method looks like:

```
ProvisioningManager manager = new ProvisioningManager(false)
{
};

System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    this.MaxSteps = manager.MaxProgress;
}));

manager.StatusUpdated += new ProvisioningManager.StatusUpdatedHandler(manager_StatusUpdated);
manager.TaskCompleted += new ProvisioningManager.TaskCompleteHandler(manager_TaskCompleted);

manager.ProvisionClient();
while (!manager.Completed)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100 * 60);
}
```

Basically it creates the manager that handles talking to the different sub-systems which provision the client.

Now I have a status update event and completed event for the provisioning manager.  When the TaskCompleted event fires I want to be able to set a property on my display object so that the finish button in the wizard is enabled:

```
void manager_TaskCompleted(object sender, ProvisioningManager.Task taskType)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        this.ProvisioningComplete = true;
    }));
}
```

The XAML for the button looks like this:

```
<wizard:WizardPage Header="Provisioning Client..."
                               ShowBack="False" 
                               AllowBack="False" 
                               AllowFinish="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=dataObject}, Path=ProvisioningComplete}" 
                               Loaded="Provisioning_Loaded">
</wizard:WizardPage>
```

This isn't working.  Even though I make sure to hit the dispatcher thread to set the property of the display object it doesn't actually change the button to enabled until I click on the window.  Is this a bug in AvalonWizard or am I not on the correct thread to set an INotifyPropertyChanged?  Is there a way to hack this; basically can I programmatically focus the window without the mouse click?

I tired placing that while loop in the DoWork method so that I could use the BackgroundWorker's completed method:

```
void provisioningWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        this.ProvisioningComplete = true;
    }));
}
```

That doesn't work either.  What gives?!

**Update**
Here is the requested static resource instantiation for the display object:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataObject" ObjectType="{x:Type winDO:NewClientWizardDO}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

**Update II**
Here is the property and property change firer:

```
public bool ProvisioningComplete
{
    get { return this._ProvisioningComplete; }
    set
    {
        this._ProvisioningComplete = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ProvisioningComplete");
    }
}

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the declaration of your static resource "StaticResource ResourceKey=dataObject"?

Comment: @Murven, the requested code has been added to the question. Thanks for looking into this issue.

Comment: I am assuming NewClientWizardDO implements INotifyPropertyChanged and that the property ProvisioningComplete fires the PropertyChangedEvent. Can you please confirm or post the code for that class? I am sorry, I should have asked for this one as well, it is just hard to tell without being sure about this.

Comment: I may have found a hack fix for this. I added a bit of code in the view that uses the PropertyChanged event for the display object.  When it finds that the ProvisioningComplete has changed and it is true I get the wizard page and call "UpdateLayout".  This seems to work, but I haven't tested it all the way yet.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but the "UpdateLayout" didn't work.  I thought it did, but I may have moved from one screen and then gave focus back to the window which caused the button to enable. Still stuck on this...

Comment: Everything looks in order, are you sure you are running the background process on the exact same instance you are binding to? If you try to set ProvisioningComplete without using the UI Dispatcher, do you get a cross-thread exception at all or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find out exactly why I was having this issue.  I tried setting focus to the window, the button, etc.  I tried multiple ways of letting the view know the viewmodel had updated.  Basically every suggestion I could find on the web didn't work.  It almost seems like a bug.

A smarty on my team suggested faking a mouse click on the window.  His idea was that since all it took to activate the button was a simple mouse click on the screen then faking one should have the same effect.  I thought (and think) that this hack was ridiculous.  I did try it out just to see if I could call it a "solution".

Well, it worked.  We had this same problem in another one of our wizards (not AvalonWizard but a homegrown one).  I think there has to be some underlying issue with the way the window redraws after a background thread updates objects that are bound to the UI.

Anyhow, the way I found to solve this issue is with the following hack-tastic code.

```
//import user32.dll and setup the use of the mouse_event method
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

/// <summary>
/// Watches for properties to change on the data object, mainly the ProvisioningComplete method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void DataObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "ProvisioningComplete":
            //if the provisioning is completed then we need to make the finish button selectable.
            if (this.DataObject.ProvisioningComplete)
            {
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    //give the window focus
                    this.Focus();
                    //update the layout
                    WizardPageProvisioningClient.UpdateLayout();
                    //fake mouse click 50 pixels into the window
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (uint)(this.Left + 50), (uint)(this.Top + 50), 0, 0);
                }));
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I've tested this when the window is not the active window and when the user leaves the window as selected.  The focus method seems to take care of this issue when the window isn't active.  Our QA team hasn't run a complete test against the UI so I can't say if there is any situations where it doesn't work, but it seems to be the best solution that I've come up with to date.

I'm open to any other suggestions if anyone out there has a better idea of what could be causing the button to not update.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I don't understand something, but is the ProvisioningComplete property marked as "volatile"? If not then this might be the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by marking something volatile.  Is this a binding markup or an attribute on the property?

Comment: there is an example and short explanation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/x13ttww7(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This seems to make sense but alas, with no user activity on the screen the button does not change states from disabled to enabled even after adding the volatile keyword to the field behind the property.  I'm beginning to think it may be an AvalonWizard bug.